# How to access a remote file in a windows drive from Ubuntu using php

Tags: php, windows, linux, exec, network-drive

I had this command in windows:

```
exec('copy /V "'.$file.'" "'.$dest.'"');
```

where $file is a REMOTE file in a windows drive of the form:

```
\\server\dr1$\folder\file
\\server\dr2$\folder\file
\\server\dr0$\folder\file
\\server\dr1$\folder\file2
\\server\dr1$\folder\file1
```

and so on. And destination is a local file in the server. Notice that drives change all the time, and that there are not known in advance (they come from a db result). In Windows everything is fine, the executed command will be something like this (/V is to verify the file is copied correctly):

```
copy /V \\server\dr1$\folder\file c:\users\test\file
```

however, I don't know how to run that in Linux, when I try

```
cp \\server\dr1$\folder\file /home/test/file
```

I get:

```
cp: cannot stat '\\server\dr1$\folder\file': No such file or directory.
```

Thanks,

Nano.

Comment: mounting is not a solution, the problem is that "sharenames" (dr1$, dr0$, etc) are unknown and there are many of them, the values come from db. They can change without notice

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Samba/CIFS to mount the drive before you copy to/from it.

This would look something like:

```
mount -t cifs //servername/sharename ./mountpoint/
cp ./mntpoint/folder/file /home/test/file
```

Theres quite a bit of documentation on this. Try googling smbclient or cifs.

Comment: The problem is that "sharename" is unknown and there are many of them, the values come from db. They can change without notice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP to exec `smbclient`commands. Smbclient behaves much the same like FTP, there are a couple of classes out there to assist you on the PHP side of things.

Alternatively you can mount the filesystem in user space via FUSE (look at https://serverfault.com/search?q=fuse+cifs for that),  copy the files and unmount the drive again.